# The most suitable plot to visualize probabilities with Seaborn

Tags: python, matplotlib, dataframe, seaborn

I'm experimenting with Seaborn using 'Titanic' Data set and have used a Bar plot to visualize passenger classes with regard to the highest probability to survive.

Now I wonder if there is a better way to visualize such data with Seaborn? Any visualization ideas are welcome.

```
df2.groupby(['Survived', 'Pclass']).size().unstack().plot(kind='bar', stacked=True)
```

[image]

Comment: You might be interested in some correlation plots - correlating probability of surviving to various factors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To graph the proportion of passengers who survived in each class, you can do the following.

```
import seaborn as sns

sns.set(style='ticks', context='talk')
titanic = sns.load_dataset('titanic')

ax = sns.pointplot('pclass', 'survived', data=titanic, join=False, palette='Set2')
ax.set_ylim(0, 1)
sns.despine()
```

[image]

If you are interested in the correlations between passenger class and survival (as per the comment from @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ), you can find that out like so:

```
# Create binary dummy variables for each passenger class
titanic['pclass1'] = titanic['pclass'] == 1
titanic['pclass2'] = titanic['pclass'] == 2
titanic['pclass3'] = titanic['pclass'] == 3
# Create correlation matrix only for the columns of interest
plot_data = (titanic[['survived', 'pclass1', 'pclass2', 'pclass3']]
    .corr()
    .loc['survived', 'pclass1':]
    .to_frame()
    .T)
# Plot the correlation coefficients
ax = sns.barplot(data=plot_data)
ax.axhline(0, color='black')
sns.despine()
```

The default correlation method for `.corr()` is to compute the Pearson correlation coefficient (r), which is a suitable choice for calculating the correlation between binary variables as per [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phi_coefficient) and [this stats prof via Quora](https://www.quora.com/Is-it-possible-to-calculate-correlations-between-binary-variables/answer/Rebecca-Warner-4).

[image]

---

#### Update 2017-10-18

A more scalable way to create dummy variables it to use `pd.get_dummies()`. So `plot_data` could be generated without the individual column assignments:

```
plot_data = (pd.concat(
    [pd.get_dummies(titanic['pclass'], prefix='pclass', prefix_sep=''),
        titanic['survived']], axis=1)
    .corr()
    .loc['survived', 'pclass1':]
    .to_frame()
    .T)
```